# Why is Output Stream not available when a custom TextWriter is used, after upgrading project to VS 2010?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I upgraded a project I did in Visual Studio 2008 to VS 2010 and now the following line won't compile

```
using (TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(_viewContext.HttpContext.Response.OutputStream))
{
    textWriter.Write(_tag.ToString(TagRenderMode.EndTag));
}
```

The error message I'm getting is:

`OutputStream is not available when a custom TextWriter is used.`

Can anyone fill me in on what I need to do? Thanks

*Edit*: the target framework is .Net 3.5

Answer (score 0):

If you have the option of changing the code, try this instead:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(_viewContext.HttpContext.Response.OutputStream))
{
    using (TextWriter textWriter = TextWriter.Synchronized(sw))
    {
        textWriter.Write(_tag.ToString(TagRenderMode.EndTag));
    }
}
```